# simple tutorial for DCOM

Tags: com, dcom, visual-c++

Can someone suggest me beginners learning resources for DCOM technology using vc++
Those with Sample codes would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [COM(C++) Programming Tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938435/comc-programming-tutorials)

Comment: @bdonlan - disagree - this is asking specifically about DCOM, not just COM. Related, but NOT a dupe.

Comment: This is so a dupe. DCOM is just COM with some configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at codeproject.com "DCOM D-Mystified: A DCOM Tutorial" - seven articles & sources for beginers

Answer (score 1):

It depends quite a bit on your exp level with COM. Moving to DCOM is really just a matter of creating an EXE-server, registering it on the remote machine and instantiating it via CoCreateInstanceEx.

You can create simple servers using the ATL app-wizard in VS.  MSDN has a number of samples you can d/l.

I realize this isn't a tutorial but you haven't really stated what you know now.